# Weird ALB behaviour when restricting access via CloudFront IPs only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have created a solution which has the following components:

- Route53 record pointing to a Cloud Front Distribution (CFD)
- A CFD pointing to an Application Load Balancer (ALB)
- An ALB with a Target Group (TG) which points to EC2 machines

Since I want to ensure that only requests coming from the CFD are accepted by my ALB, I followed the steps from this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/automatically-update-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-ip-ranges-using-aws-lambda/) to create Security Groups (SG) allowing only AWS IPs tagged as (CLOUDFRONT).

I associated the newly created SGs and kept an existing SG (which just allowed my IP) and everything seemed to be working fine (I tested it from different IPs).
However as soon as I removed the SG which just allowed my IP, **I could not access the EC2 instance anymore** (even from different computers/mobile).

**Why would removing that specific SG would "break" my solution?**

**ALB**
[image]

**Default SG**
[image]

**One of the three CFD IPs SGs**
[image]

**CloudFront**
[image]
[image]

**Route 53**

[image]

Comment: Since you set your `ALB` to accept requests only from `CFD`, Are you sure that you are not accessing instances directly?

Comment: I am 106% sure. I am accessing the instance via my Route53 record. I have added a screenshot of it.

Comment: I am suspecting maybe your request going through a `CFD` which's `IP` is not updated in `SG`. Anyway allowing `CloudFront` using `IPs` is way more complicated. Did you try restricting using `Custom Header` that should be sent by your `CFD` only?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html

Comment: That is a great idea!